# java- I need a value to only be used in the while loop and not get assigned

Tags: java

Hello I'm having difficulty keeping "EXTERMINATE" from being assigned as one of the variables, I only want it to be used so that the while loop knows when to end, is this possible, that the value isn't assigned to the variable and used just for the loop?
EDIT:

```
public static void ello() {
    String ans1 = "";

    String number1input = "";

    String ans2 = "";

    String number2input = "";

    int number1 = 0;

    int number2 = 0;
    while (!ans1.equals("EXTERMINATE") || !ans2.equals("EXTERMINATE")) {
        ans1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name an animal?");

        if (ans1.equals("EXTERMINATE")) {
            break;
        }
        number1input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many are left in the wild?");
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(number1input);
        ans2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name an animal?");
        if (ans2.equals("EXTERMINATE")) {
            break;
        }
        number2input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many are left in the wild?");
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(number2input);
        if (number1 <= number2) {
            number2 = number1;
            ans2 = ans1;
        } else {
            number1 = number2;
            ans1 = ans2;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: please share datatype of ans1 and ans2

Comment: What do you want it to be if a user types this word?

Comment: Done, its near the top. Im sorry for the hassle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a different variable for the data from JOptionPane and then assign the value of that variable to `ans1` after checking that it is not "EXTERMINATE"

Replace

```
int number2 = 0;
while (!ans1.equals("EXTERMINATE") || !ans2.equals("EXTERMINATE")) {
    ans1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name an animal?");

    if (ans1.equals("EXTERMINATE")) {
        break;
    }
```

with

```
int number2 = 0;
String tempAns;
while (true) {
    tempAns = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name an animal?");
    if ("EXTERMINATE".equals(tempAns)) {
        break;
    }
    ans1 = tempAns;
```

Now `ans1` won't get the chance to contain "EXTERMINATE".  Also note `while(true)` because you are `break`ing on both of the conditions that were in your original `while` loop.

SIDE NOTE: It is better to write

```
"EXTERMINATE".equals(tempAns)
```

rather than

```
tempAns.equals("EXTERMINATE")
```

if `tempAns` is null the former is safe whereas the latter will throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I cant do it. I apologise for my incompetency I'm new to java

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know how or that this won't work for your particular situation?  I edited my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Thank you, all this was missing was to do the same to the second answer but I got that. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Ok , i think i got it.
If somebody inputs "EXTERMINATE" to your statements like

```
ans1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name an animal?");
```

Then definitely, ans1 is assigned with "EXTERMINATE";

And It's impossible to prevent that "EXTERMINATE" to be assigned in ans1;

Acc. to me, you can achieve your goal as

```
while (ans1.equals("EXTERMINATE"))
        {   
             ans1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name an animal?");
        }
```

with an error message i.e "EXTERMINATE not accepted"

Comment: yes what you said is true, the user doesnt want to do that and is asking if its possible

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. Do you have an idea how I could make the code work as intended?

Comment: I've edited my code, It'll check the user input as "EXTERMINATE" and ask the user to again type something else. May it complete your goal

Comment: The thing is I need EXTERMINATE to end the while loop

Comment: Yes but Im trying to avoid it being assigned ?

Comment: @Thevenin the last suggestion appeals to me, ill be sure to let you know how it goes